# $\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ if $E(X_1^2) < \infty$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence

if $X1,X2,\dots,X_n$ are identically distributed (not necessarily idendependent) such that $E(X_1^2) < \infty$ then $\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ where $M_n = max\{|X_1|,|X_2|,\dots,|X_n|\}$.

My attempt:
$P(M_n > \epsilon \sqrt{n}) \leq \sum^n_{i=1}P(X_i >\epsilon \sqrt{n}) < \frac{E(X_1^2)}{n}$ . But this sum doesn't converge to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Any hint regarding which inequality to use will be helpful.

Comment: $\frac{M_n}{n} \to 0$ almost surely, you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y \geq 0$ and $EY^{2} <\infty$ then $\sum P(Y^{2}>n) <\infty$. Taking $Y=\frac {|X_1|} {\sqrt {\epsilon}}$ we see that $\sum P(|X_1| > \sqrt {\epsilon }n)=\sum P(|X_1|^{2}>\epsilon n)<\infty$. This gives $\sum P(|X_n| > \sqrt {\epsilon n})<\infty$. So $|X_n| \leq  \sqrt {\epsilon }n$ for all large $n$ with probability $1$. Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary this implies that $\frac {M_n} {\sqrt n}$  tends to $0$ almost surely.